# Struts2 JSP Map

Tags: jsp, dictionary, struts2

In jsp, I have:

```
<s:set name="gender" value="#{'':'gender', 'm':'Male', 'f':'Female'}"/>
```

The property `user.gender` can be empty, `m`, or `f`. What I want is to display either `Male` or `Female` from the defined `gender` map.

I tried `<s:property value="gender[%{#user.gender}]"/>` but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `#` sign to access value which is set in `<s:set>` tag.

```
<s:property value="#gender[user.gender]"/>
```

Comment: I assume you have fixed single quotes inside `<s:set>` tag? Also where do you get your `user` property?

Comment: when I have `<s:property value="user.gender"/>` this will display either `m` or `f`

Comment: Then why do you use `#` before it in property? Try this `<s:property value="#gender[user.gender]"/>`.

Comment: Have you fixed single quotes?

Comment: @JRGalia What, did you think I was kidding about the quotes? +1 for persistence and catching the missing `#`.

Comment: Is the leading # needed? In recent vers was this not changed? On phone can't test.

Answer (score 4):

Single-quoted, single-characters in OGNL are actual `char`s, not `String`s.

If the user's gender is a `String` the map should use double-quoted, single-characters as the key.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<s:property value="getText('properties.name')"/> //this is to fetch value from properties file
```

so answer to your question is sumthing like this

```
<s:property value="getText('user.gender')"/>
```

Comment: While this doesn't directly address the OP's question, allowing gender names to be localized is probably a better idea in the long run.

Comment: I just given him a solution for his question, however he can achieve gender names using this solution

Comment: Which is why I said that it was probably a good idea to use I18N for this, even though the OP didn't ask.